# ¿Cómo permitir ÚNICAMENTE mails con protocolo SMTP en WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, smtp

Así es señores, deseo buscar la forma de bloquear las funciones que usa WordPress por defecto para enviar los mails, sin perjudicar el envío por SMTP.

Intentaré explicarme mejor, por defecto WordPress envía correos electrónicos (no sé como se denominan, digamos NO-SMTP), luego de instalar un plugin como lo es "Easy SMTP WP" y otro plugin como Ninja Form dejamos de usar esos mails, pero me gustaría poder bloquearlos.

Hasta el momento lo he intentado, pero me bloquea los mails SMTP también, yo probé con un plugin llamado "Disable emails", creo que bloquea todas las funciones de correo. ¿La función wp-mail() es la encargada de enviar mail por SMTP también?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero una aclaración, Wordpress se apoya en la librería PHPMailer para el envío de correos.

Cuando uno configura SMTP lo que hace es pasarle a esa librería los parámetros necesarios para que se contacte con un servidor externo a través del cual hacer el envío.

Si no configurás nada, Wordpress, le indica a la librería que utilice la función mail() de PHP por defecto. Esta función toma sus parámetros del archivo de configuración de PHP y su funcionamiento va a depender de lo que diga este.

Volviendo a Wordpress, la forma de pasarle tu propia configuración por defecto a PHPMailer es a través del hook [phpmailer_init](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init) que nos da acceso directo a la librería.

Te copio el ejemplo tomado de la documentación:

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer_example' );
function my_phpmailer_example( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();     
    $phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true; // Force it to use Username and Password to authenticate
    $phpmailer->Port = 25;
    $phpmailer->Username = 'yourusername';
    $phpmailer->Password = 'yourpassword';

    // Additional settings…
    //$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = "tls"; // Choose SSL or TLS, if necessary for your server
    //$phpmailer->From = "you@yourdomail.com";
    //$phpmailer->FromName = "Your Name";
}
```

Y [acá](https://gist.github.com/butlerblog/c5c5eae5ace5bdaefb5d) te dejo otro.

Lo más probable es que el plugin que estes usando ya lo haga de esta manera.

En lo que respecta a WP y a la función wp_mail(), todos los correos que se envíen lo haran con esa configuración. Esto no si o si tiene que aplicar a otros plugins instalados que envíen correo.

Comment: Perfectamente explicado, te agradezco por haberte tomado la molestia de escribir todo detallado.